# How to record 2-day trek track when Garmin etreX 20 has limitation of 2000 points?

Tags: trekking, gps

There is a limitation of 2000 points in `Garmin etrex 20`. I have bought it recently and have not used it for a real trek. As far as I know when you reach the 2000 points limit and want to save it, the device will remove extra points. So you will not have an accurate track. What is the solution to this problem? Should I add an SD card? Will it save me in the wild? Or should I save track every 5 hours in order to prevent it from removing extra point?

Comment: The limit is 10000 trackpoints, not 2000. The eTrex 20 will not remove points when saving. You can set it to archive daily and start with a clean Current track.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I rarely use GPS system personally so feel free to correct me if I've misunderstood something.

However, I think that 2000 points should be more than enough.

Say you are doing a reasonably long route of 40km per day. If you use all 2000 points in that distance that will give you one point every 20m. Give that the accuracy of your GPS under some conditions is probably about the same as this, more points won't really help.

For comparison when using a paper map I guess I will look at the map maybe 100 times in such a walk although it is dependent on terrain and (mentally or physically) I will actually mark 10-20 points per day.

From a safety point of view the GPS should provide your position irrespective of the route you have set. So this should not be a factor.

Reading your question again I think you might actually be talking about saving the route you've been. In any case my point on the distance per point still stands.

A quick look at the model in question shows that 2000 is the number of locations you can save.  It can save 200 routes each of (up to)? 10000 points. So you should have no problems in that regard.